# OBIEE 11 Can't display fields in csv exported file

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, obiee

How can I choose which fields to display in the CSV file I export, and how can I control their order? The fields I want to export are excluded from view, but I would like to have them in csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything selected in the Criteria tab and not "Hidden" will be in the CSV in the order specified in the Criteria tab.